# How to change DBeaver timezone / How to stop DBeaver from converting date and time

Tags: timezone, dbeaver

When I use DBeaver with Cassandra, it shows an offset of +01:00 even though the data is stored in Date or Times formats, that don't have any timezones. This results in some weird queries like this:

```
SELECT "Time"
FROM keyspace."Table"
ORDER BY "Time" DESC;

Time
00:00:00
23:00:00
22:00:00
...
01:00:00
```

So, how do I remove the conversions or do I set the timezone to UTC?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I found another solution:

> Setting `dbeaver.ini` file in DBeaver root directory.

Open the file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-showsplash
# START: change jre version, not using the one in %JAVA_HOME%
-vm 
D:\ArPortable\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
# END
# JVM settings
-vmargs
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms64m
-Xmx1024m
# time zone
-Duser.timezone=UTC
# language
-Duser.language=en
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the server timezone isn't UTC, or if you use multiple servers with different timezones. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54401047/8213783)

Comment: This fixed the "ERROR: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "Europe/Berlin"" for me with using CockroachDB on Windows 10.

Comment: See my answer below - there is a much easier option in settings UI starting in v22.1. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72533665/220997

Answer (score 58):

v22.1.0 added this preference in the UI (no more modifying `.ini` files).

In Window -> Preferences. Go to User Interface and change the Client Timezone. Restart dbeaver.

Github PR here: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/pull/16467

[image]

Comment: Simple and works, pls upvote!

Comment: Best option. This should be accepted answer now.

Comment: I don't want any timezone conversion, even to UTC, but view the timestamp as stored in the DB. As much as I prefer DBeaver over pgAdmin, I am forced to use pgAdmin when performing timezone-sensitive operations because I am unsure where DBeaver's "helpful" conversion is kicking in. Can you show me how to disable the feature completely?

Answer (score 24):

DBeaver uses the time in the computer that is installed, so changing the clock and restarting DBeaver works. But there is a way to do it only for DBeaver instead.

- Close DBeaver.
- Go to the DBeaver shortcut. Probably it is here:

  `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\DBeaver`
- Right-click on it, choose Properties and in the **Target** box add `-vmargs -Duser.timezone=UTC` to the end, resulting in something like this:

  `"C:\Program Files\DBeaver\dbeaver.exe" -vmargs -Duser.timezone=UTC`
- Start DBeaver and the times now appear in UTC.

Comment: Providing those parameters to the program didn't work for me, but I was able to just modify **dbeaver.ini** and add the `vmarg` there. Then it worked.

Comment: I had to add `-Duser.timezone=UTC` on the line just below `-vmargs` in __dbeaver.ini__, and restart the app.  Putting it on the same line did not work.  And this was inside the app package on MacOS, so it's bound to be overwritten during the next app update.

Comment: @JohnLemberger That putting a configuration option on the same line as `-vmargs` doesn't work is expected: since DBeaver is Eclipse-based, [Eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) settings and rules apply.

Comment: can you give an example for setting Europe/Berlin timezone in dbeaver.ini? I tried

-vmargs
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Berlin

Comment: @LeeviL I would not advise using anything other than UTC for the reasons stated in the question. But for your case, if Europe/Berlin does not work, try CET, or +01:00 or related.

Comment: It's kind of crazy that there's no way to tell DBeaver to use the server's time zone in a way that persists across updates.

Answer (score 15):

**On Mac**

1. Go to Finder > Applications
2. Right click on DBeaver and select Show Package Contents
3. Open Contents\Eclipse\dbeaver.ini
4. After the -vmargs line, add this: -Duser.timezone=UTC
5. Save file and restart DBeaver

Limitation: You’ll have to redo this for every version upgrade.

**Windows**

1. Go to DBeaver install directory C:\Program Files\DBeaver
2. Open dbeaver.ini
3. After the -vmargs line, add this: -Duser.timezone=UTC
4. Save file and restart DBeaver

Source: [This blog](https://joshpeng.github.io/post/dbeaver_tz/)

Answer (score 13):

UPDATE 2021-04-05: Based on recent comments I need to clear that this solution suitable only for Clickhouse DB. Additionally it is very old answer, please, take in mind that it is currently 99% outdated solution.

I think it was fixed in some previous release.

Just go to Settings -> Editors -> Data Formats and select 'Use native date/time format' checkbox.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me, dates and times are still converted to local time

Comment: @Wes I have double checked solution and it works for me. But this works for a DBeaver 5.3.2 and Clickhouse database for a fields with DateTime type

Comment: If it helps, I am working in Postgres and running `to_timestamp()` on an epoch timestamp.  The solutions above worked for me though.

Comment: No, this does **_not work_**.  It only affects the **_format_** of timestamps (i.e., "YYYY-MM-DD" vs. "MM-DD-YYYY", etc.), not the **_value_** displayed (i.e., UTC vs. your local time zone).

Answer (score 7):

If you wanna see the TimeZone of your `Selects`, you can go to *DBeaver Preferences*:

Preferences
[image]

1. Click on **Type**, and change it to *Timestamp*
2. In **Pattern Value** add the termination " Z z" and see the **Sample** result like this: 2019-11-06 07:38:54 -0300 BRT
3. Tap **Apply**, and **Apply and Close**
4. Done :)

Answer (score 7):

### For DBeaver in Linux

1. Quit DBeaver if it's running.
2. Edit `/usr/share/dbeaver/dbeaver.ini`, adding `-Duser.timezone=UTC` to `-vmargs` section. E.g.:

   ```
    -vmargs
    -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
    --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11
    -Xms64m
    -Xmx1024m
    -Duser.timezone=UTC
   ```
3. Open DBeaver and view timestamps in UTC.

### Viewing full timestamp values

1. Window > Preferences
2. Editors > Data Editor > Data Formats
3. Check 'Disable date/time formatting'

Before: `2021-04-19 16:14:23`

After: `2021-04-19 16:14:23.056178+00`

Tested with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 4):

If this is the JDBC driver issue with regards to the timezone:
Right click on the connection to open connection settings

[image: right click on the connection to open connection settings]

change the timezone
[image: change the timezone for the connection]

OR you may also change the server timezone driver property
[image: OR you may change the server timezone driver property]

Answer (score 4):

As of today (DBeaver 21.3.2 CE) you need to go to Window > Preferences.
In the dialog pop-up window choose: Editors > Data Editor > Formats, then choose Timestamp in the dropdown in the Format frame and click on Timesone line.

[image]

Right-click there and print **UTC**

[image]

Click the '**Apply and Close**' button in the lower right corner.
**Done!**