# postgresql timezone difference between Navicat and DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver, navicat

I have an application generating an expiration timestamp. I had some problems, so I debugged around a bit and it confuses me more and more.

I use this example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2013-08-13 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

When I run this in **Navicat**, I get back

```
timezone
----------------------
2013-08-12 22:00:00+00
```

When I run this code in **DBeaver**, I get back

```
timezone
-------------------
2013-08-13 02:00:00
```

It is the same DB, the same user, the same schema, the only difference is the client programm from which I call this example.
Where does the difference between the results come from?

Comment: A time zone configuration for the current session can be set when connecting to a database. Different Clients connect to the database in different ways. One client may send a time zone configuration for the session, the other one may not (in this case the default server time zone is used). It seems you can see the current time zone configuration with "show timezone;"

Comment: Yes, that is also what I think. But I do not know where to explicitly tell the program or the connection wihich timezone to use. Or how do I tell that to the pg_connect.

Comment: This seems to be an issue of different presentation/formatting in Navicat & DBeaver. I think that explicit formatting, i.e. `select to_char(timestamp '2013-08-13 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSOF');` will produce consistent results.

Comment: For `DBeaver`  you should take a look at Aashutosh Taikar's answer(at bottom) from this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323552/how-to-change-dbeaver-timezone-how-to-stop-dbeaver-from-converting-date-and-ti/54401047#54401047)