# Postgres UTC timezone, now() returns 2 hour offset

Tags: postgresql

I set the Postgres timezone to UTC using:

```
SET timezone = 'UTC';
```

But then when I do:

```
select now();
```

It returns the following result:

```
2023-06-04 14:06:08.428 +0200
```

I was expecting the result to just be in UTC format: `2023-06-04 12:06:08.428`.

I am aware that I can use `select now()::timestamp` to get the UTC value, but I am wondering:

Where does this `+0200` come from, if I set the timezone to UTC using `SET`?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure you are doing the same thing that you are asking about?

Comment: @wilx Yes, am sure. I execute these 2 commands: SET timezone = 'UTC';
select now();

Comment: 1) I cannot reproduce. 2) What is the default timezone set in `postgresql.conf`? 3) What client are you using to run the commands? 4) `select now()::timestamp` will not get the `UTC` value it will just be `2023-06-04 14:06:08.428`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 2) The default timezone in .conf file is: timezone = 'Etc/UTC' 3) I am using DBeaver. Also I am using the postgis/postgis:15-3.3 docker image.  4) Oh okay, thank you for the information.

Comment: @IvanGandacov.  Using `psql` do: 1) `SHOW timezone;` and if not `UTC`, then `SET timezone = 'UTC';`. 2) `select now();`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that either. Perhaps you are running the two statements in different database sessions (connection pool).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I think it is related to [DBeaver Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323552/how-to-change-dbeaver-timezone-how-to-stop-dbeaver-from-converting-date-and-ti/72533665#72533665).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, just set the DBeaver Timezone to UTC, and the output is in UTC. Thank you! Does it mean that probably the DBeaver JDBC driver converts the output to its own timezone?

Comment: Pretty sure yes. The way to confirm is to crank up the Postgres logging(temporarily) in `postgresql.conf` [What to log](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) *log_statement = 'all'*. Then look at the Postgres log to see what happens when you connect.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the best way to get UTC time is to ask for `now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't answer my question. I am wondering why +2 offset is returned by now() if zone was set to UTC.

Comment: i believe because it's dbeaver, but not psql.