# Power BI missing rows from direct query with SQL

Tags: sql, powerbi, amazon-redshift

Here are the results I get running SQL against Redshift:

[image: sql query against redshift]

However, when I run the same SQL against the same database using a direct query and custom SQL with Power BI, only rows with IDs greater than 15256612 show up, and I have no idea why.

Here's the query setup:

[image]

And here's the preview:

[image]

For the sake of this demo, I used a brand new report, so there are no existing filters or references to any other data. I couldn't even begin to guess why a BI tool running direct SQL would exclude these records.

Comment: What happens if you include ORDER BY clause into **both** queries and THEN compare results they return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the client I was using to develop was defaulting to my local time zone, so the view I created was returning different values when run by clients defaulting to UTC. See [How to change DBeaver timezone / How to stop DBeaver from converting date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323552/how-to-change-dbeaver-timezone-how-to-stop-dbeaver-from-converting-date-and-ti)